# Google Sheets: computing form data with multiple answers. arraformula, Split and transpose

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got a form which people can use to sign up however in order to make it easier instead of making someone submit multiple forms for each event they want to sign we want to make the event dropdown multiple choice which means they can select multiple. However in google sheets it will put all those events in 1 cell with comma separation. What I need in the end is for each event to get 1 row.
E.g.
Input:

| Timestamp | Event | First name | last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2021 18:11:01 | Event A | Jane | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event A, Event B | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event B, Event C | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event A, Event C | John | Smit |

output:

| Timestamp | Event | First name | last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2021 18:11:01 | Event A | Jane | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event A | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event B | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event B | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event C | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event A | John | Smit |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event C | John | Smit |

link is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YLEYZ0pBIXi6j28X-pAVb09ESbtvWhrvNOXpjTIO5JM/edit?usp=sharing

Tried multiple formula combinations but havent gotten it to work

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the knowledge on doing it using formulas. But I suggest using Google Apps Script [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). You can basically trigger your script every time, there is a new row in your spreadsheet. It might be more challenging than formulas but this tool gives you much more power over the data. You would basically need to write a javascript function.

In the script, check the content of the column `Event`, if you find a comma, split content of this cell into an array. Then, copy the whole row and insert it again as a new row for every element of your array.

I would treat one of the sheets in your document as input from the form. Create another sheet, let's call it `output`. Then the script would analyze each row in the input sheet. If there is no comma in the `Event` column, you just copy the row to the output sheet. If there is a comma, split it into different rows.

Here is the reference to all functions you can use to manipulate data from Google Sheets [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

---

I just found a close-enough way of doing it. This way, the timestamp is in a different position but that's not a big problem. Try a formula like this:

```
=Query(ArrayFormula(split(trim(flatten(split(B2:B1000,",")&"|"&C2:C1000&"|"&C2:C1000)&"|"&D2:D1000),"|")),"Select * where Col3 is not null")
```

B column must be the one that is being split. All the other columns that need to be copied over are listed by adding `&"|"&X2:X1000` before the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to go down the code route you could use this function.

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  let output = [];
  input.forEach(row => {
    const events = row[1].split(',');
    events.forEach(event=>{
      output.push([row[0], event.trim(), row[2], row[3], row[4]]);
      })
    }
  )
  
  return output
}
```

Pass it the range that the original data is in, for example.

```
=myFunction(A2:D6)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via formula:

```
=query(
{A3:A,ArrayFormula(ifna(substitute(regexextract(B3:B,"^.+,|.+"),",",""))),C3:D;
A3:A,ArrayFormula(ifna(substitute(regexextract(B3:B,", .+$"),", ",""))),C3:D},
"select * where Col2 is not null order by Col1")
```

Explanation:
First I take whole table and from 2nd column I take the values before comma or whole value when there is no comma (regexextact). Then I remove comma (with substitute).
Then I go through this table again and take all the values from the 2nd column that are after comma (and remove comma and space).
Finally I sort everything by timestamp and remove cells with empty values.

[image]

My solution is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GaDtD5vu4OEnRPlAopQJG4c7M-f6ezlnfpo1uTBGu6A/copy

Answer (score 0):

another way close to rogowskibart'one with the right sequence of columns and the headers

```
={"Timestamp","Event","First name","Last name";
Query(
ArrayFormula(split(trim(flatten(split(B3:B,",")&"|"&C3:C&"|"&D3:D&"|"&A3:A)),"|")),
"Select Col4,Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 is not null")
}
```